# add security to unsecure PHP mysql script semi automatically

Tags: php, mysql, security, automation, notepad++

I have a lot of files which have things like

```
1- mysql_query("update ... $_POST['foo'] ...");
```

I want to transform that to this

```
2- $foo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['foo']);
3- mysql_query("update ... $foo ...");
```

I had the idea to open each file, select the text `$_POST['foo']` (form 1-) press a key combination, and then some tool automatically:

- put on my clipboard `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['foo']);` (for adding in 2-)
- replace the text in 1- with the text in 3-

Then manually write `$foo =` and press ctrl+v to generate 2-

I'm trying with notepad++ and a plugin called fingertext, and trying to make a macro, but had no success.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like this question only pertains to some sort of text editor or macro.

Comment: I'm willing to use any solution, but prefer to use some text editor or macro, as you say (not only notepad++, not only windows but also linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_POST = sanitize($_POST);
$_GET = sanitize($_GET);

    function sanitize($input) {
        if (is_array($input)) {
            foreach($input as $var=>$val) {
                $output[$var] = sanitize($val);
            }
        } else {
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $input = stripslashes($input);
            }
            $output = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
        }
        return $output;
    }
```

It's not perfect, but if you have a lot of unsecure pages and need a quick fix to make them all secure, you can put this after connecting to mysql. also, keep in mind that if your query has unquoted numbers variables, you will have to either validate that they are numbers, or type cast them before using them in your query. mysql_real_escape_string() only works on quoted values (ie blah_column = 'value', but not blah_column = value).

Comment: Nice. Only a problem if vars inside are not string but int. I guess it could be used some cast+exception mechanism. I'll try and edit accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Replace them one by one , with hand. If you care about security, dont make autoreplace. And also make a function at least instead of `mysql_real_escape_string(()` , use it.

```
 //just for example, better can be written
function db_escape($var, $type = 'string') 
{
   if($type == 'string') return mysql_real_escape_string($var);
   if($type == 'integer') return (int) $var;
   if($type == 'float') return (float) $var;
}
```

Comment: why would I need that function? Do you intend it for better maintainability?

Comment: @jperelli its just example. you can write better one.